# Comment indenting seems messed up in clojure-mode

Tags: emacs, clojure, tabs

In clojure-mode emacs is indenting my semi colon comments with 5 tabs. Even if it is the first line in an empty file this occurs.

Eg just open up a clojure file, enter ; at the first character and press tab.

I'm using version 1.7.1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's normal behavior. In your case you want two semicolons (;;).

---

From Tutorial on [Good Lisp Programming Style by Peter Norvig (pdf)](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~nau/cmsc421/norvig-lisp-style.pdf) -- page 41:

> Obey comment conventions:
>
> - ; for inline comment
> - ;; for    in-function comment
> - ;;; for    between-function comment
> - ;;;; for    section header (for outline mode)

These comment tips are written for emacs lisp, but they are the same for all lisps: http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Comment-Tips.html

```
(setq base-version-list                           ; there was a base
                (assoc (substring fn 0 start-vn)  ; version to which
                       file-version-assoc-list))  ; this looks like
                                                  ; a subversion
                                                  ;
                                                  ;
                                                  ;
                                                  ;    again, 
                                                  ;    this is inline comment


;; two semicolon comment
;; aligned to the same level of indentation as the code
```

Comment: Oh! That's fair enough. My Common Lisp mode never enforced this but I guess I should get into better habits. +1 for the link to that book

Comment: Those column aligned comments would make programming in a variable width font really awkward.  Are there any more modern competing styles?

Comment: @pauldoo You code in a variable width font? That must be terrible.