# What is the difference between ; and ;; in Clojure code comments?

Tags: clojure, comments, marginalia

What is the difference between `;` and `;;` when starting a comment in Clojure?  I see that my [text editor](http://jedit.org) colours them differently, so I'm assuming there is notionally some difference.

I also see that [Marginalia](http://fogus.me/fun/marginalia/) treats them differently:

```
; Stripped entirely
;; Appears in text section of marginalia
(defn foobar []
   ; Appears in code section of marginalia output
   ;; Again, appears in code section of marginalia output
   6)
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There is no difference as far as the interpreter is concerned. Think of `;` `;;` `;;;` and `;;;;` as different heading levels.

Here is my personal use convention:

```
;;;; Top-of-file level comments, such as a description of the whole file/module/namespace

;;; Documentation for major code sections (i.e. groups of functions) within the file.

;; Documentation for single functions that extends beyond the doc string (e.g. an explanation of the algorithm within the function)

; In-line comments possibly on a single line, and possibly tailing a line of code
```

Comment: I guess I have to mark this as correct given the number of upvotes.  An external reference would be nice, but I guess it's an unwritten culture thing. :)

Comment: For reference, Peter Norvig, the author of *Good Lisp Programming Style*, among a lot of other things, refers to this convention as a "near standard". http://stackoverflow.com/a/4531930/603891

Comment: Then why no mention of single `;` in the doc? https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comment

Comment: @matanster That link is about (comment) not ;. But FTR the second paragraph in the largest example does indeed discuss a single ;. For canonical doc on the ; reader macro check https://clojure.org/reference/reader#macrochars

Answer (score 34):

Check out the [official description](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Comment-Tips.html) of the meaning of `;` vs `;;` in elisp: since the Clojure indenter is basically the same, it will treat them similarly. Basically, use `;` if you are writing a long sentence/description "in the margins" that will span multiple lines but should be considered a single entity. Their example is:

```
(setq base-version-list                 ; there was a base
      (assoc (substring fn 0 start-vn)  ; version to which
             file-version-assoc-list))  ; this looks like
                                        ; a subversion
```

The indenter will make sure those stay lined up next to each other. If, instead, you want to make several unrelated single-line comments next to each other, use `;;`.

```
(let [x 99 ;; as per ticket #425
      y "test"] ;; remember to test this
  (str x y)) ;; TODO actually write this function
```

Answer (score 16):

Emacs ; to be used for end-of-line comments and will indent in surprising ways if that is not your intent.  ;; does not so I usually use ;;.

Clojure doesn't care - any line is ignored from the ; to EOL.

I believe there is a tradition in CL of using increasing numbers of ; to indicate more important comments/sections.

Answer (score 7):

no meaning for the language. `;` is a reader macro for `comment`
perhaps other tools parse them but "within clojure" they are the same.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference from a Clojure-perspective.  I find that `;;` stands out a little better than `;`, but that's only my opinion.

Marginalia on the other hand treats them differently because there are times when a comment should remain in the code section (e.g. license) and those are flagged with `;`.  This is an arbitrary decision and may change in the future.

Comment: fogus, notice alex miller's comment about emacs. It indents single ; comments but not ;; or ;;; If you don't use emacs yourself, you should be aware of what its auto-indentation scheme does, because a lot of your target users will.

Answer (score 6):

In emacs lisp modes including clojure-mode, `;;` is formatted with the convention of being at the beginning of a line, and indented as as any other line, based on the context. `;` is expected to be used at the end of a line, so emacs will not do what you want it to if you put a single-semicolon comment at the beginning of a line expecting it to tab to the indentation for the present context.

Example:

```
(let [foo 1]
  ;; a comment
  foo) ; a comment
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure (not used Clojure and never heard of this before), but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531761/comment-indenting-seems-messed-up-in-clojure-mode) *might* help.

Comment: Those styles look completely incompatible with variable width fonts.  I hope the Clojure community hasn't adopted the column alignment thing for comments.